# Spring data JPA, complex native Query

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot and spring data JPA. It works fine but! 
I need to use complex native queries from Oracle database(source data from SAP ERP).

Lets say the query which contains 5 joned tables (one key, or composite key).
I could use a lot of parameters.

Solution:

1) It is unreal to write new query using JPA for this query due to time consuming. Creating all key relations between tables seems to be complicated.

2) To run those query I use JDBC. It is easy, because I have prepared native query. But I am convinced that this approach is not right.

Do you have any idea how to use Spring data JPA to run very complex native queries?

Thanks for advice

Comment: It may be an old question ,I was just wondering why cannot we use Simple Spring JDBC Template when our application is heavily SQL centric having multiple joins

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that you may want to revisit data model. Joining 5 tables may be quite expensive on DB resources and you data model may be more usable [de-normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

If data model is buried into stone and you don't want to use JPQL for complex queries and don't want to use plain JDBC, I believe you have two options.

1. Using [JPA criteria queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm#GJITV). They are slightly similar to [Hibernate Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), and in fact they are meant to replace them. I used only JEE6 based JPA Criteria queries and they felt little bit clunky sometimes. Not sure if it got better in JEE7.
2. You may consider using lower level query builders like [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) or [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/). I believe JOOQ is payed for Oracle. QueryDSL also has some support for JPA, but not sure what goal there is. Maybe to make JPA criteria queries slightly more usable API.

Both of the options allow use to construct type safe queries with Java chained APIs, so your query in Java code shouldn't be much more code than plain SQL.